# How To Pull Information From A Page And Input The Data In The Wordpress User Database Table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, sql-update

On my site users complete a form that is connected to an off-site third party software. Once the user clicks the submit button they are forwarded to a second page on my site that displays a unique code generated by the third party software.

What I want to do is add this unique code to the Wordpress user's meta information. I think the best way to do it is the following:

- Create a new user profile field ($unique_code)
- Scrape or pull the unique code from the page
- Identify the current user id
- Input the unique code into the user profile

My challenges are:

- How do I scrape/pull the data from the page?
- How do I add the data to the user meta without a form or submit action?

Any suggestions or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: When the page you have displays that code, then there must be a piece of code that handles this already. So, why do you need to scrape your *own* page?

Comment: The code is generated by the third party software via javascript added to the page. I know it's possible to get the code but I don't know how and don't know how to add the code to the user meta database table once I get it?